# How do I start a timer on a click?

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to have a timer start when the user makes the first click on a page. Been doing a lot of research and for the life of me, can't figure it out. I think I should use a `document.addEventListener` but am not sure where it goes.

```js
let min = 0;
let sec = 0;


function myTimer() {
  if (counting) {
    timer.innerHTML = min + " minutes " + sec + " seconds";
    sec++;
    if (sec >= 60) {
      sec = 0;
      min++;
    }
  }
}


//Start the timer

let startTimer = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.addEventListener`?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a click listener to `document` that calls the `setInterval`:

```js
let min = 0;
let sec = 0;


function myTimer() {
  timer.innerHTML = min + " minutes " + sec + " seconds";
  sec++;
  if (sec >= 60) {
    sec = 0;
    min++;
  }
}


//Start the timer
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<div id="timer">click somewhere</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a button with id `button` as so:

`<button id="button">Click me</button>`

the most basic way to add an event listener for that button to start the timer is by retrieving the element from dom (using `querySelector` or `getElementById`), then add a named event listener function to the element in the dom, such as `onclick`:

```
document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function(){
  //your code to start timeer here
};
```

but you can also do it using `addEventListener`:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',function(){
  //your code to start timeer here
});
```

or with event delegation, you can add a global click handler to the document, check if the target element was the button, and if so you can then start the timer:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  if(event.target.id==='button'){
    //your code to start timer here
  }
});
```

there are 900 ways to skin a cat in modern javascript, its up to you to decide which one is most appropriate, and sometimes its a matter of personal preference.